# Output the smallest valued duplicate in a csv file

Tags: bash, csv, awk, duplicates

I have a CSV file with a large list of duplicated items with different prices and the file is sorted.
I want to compare all the duplicated items and see which duplicated item has the lowest price and then export that duplicated item with the lowest price to a new file
the fields are separated by commas
so original CSV file:

> 01,banana,7.00
>   01,banana,6.00
>   01,banana,7.00
>   01,banana,9.00
>   02,mango,5.00
>   02,mango,3.00
>   02,mango,3.00
>   02,mango,4.00

output CSV file should be

> 01,banana,6.00
>   02,mango,3.00

im currently coding in bash and was wondering if awk could do this.

Comment: Trivial using awk, what have you tried?

Comment: well i've been searching about and tried this: awk '!x[$1,$2]++' FS=":" file.txt

Comment: but this compares the 2 columns and checks if they are the same, but obviously that is not my purpose, i just wish to find which of the duplicates is smaller

Comment: That's just counting duplicates, not comparing the prices. And `FS=":"` means that the columns are separated by `:` instead of spaces.

Comment: So write a script that saves `$3` in the associative array, and compares the new one with the saved one to see if it's smaller.

Comment: Actually, that script is just removing duplicates, not counting them.

Comment: yeh alright, to tell you the truth i'm a complete beginner to awk, but i really need to prase a csv file right now haha.

Comment: can you help me get started on how to write this script, im actually pretty lost on just how to being, im thinking it should be along the lines of `FS=","`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk '!($1" "$2 in x) || x[$1" "$2] > $3 {x[$1" "$2] = $3}
     END {for (item in x) print item, x[item]}' file.txt
```

- `$1" "$2` == the first two columns connected by a space
- `!(... in x)` == is ... not found as a key in the array `x`?
- `x[...] > $3` == is the ... element of `x` greater than column 3

So if the item number+name is not found in x, or the saved price is greater than the current row, we execute the code in braces:

- `{x[...] = $3}` == Save the price as the ... element of `x`

At the `END` we loop through all the items in `x`, and print the item and saved price.

Comment: could u explain what each of the parts mean? i want to understand this code, not just copy and paste

Comment: oh and i forgot to mention this is a csv file

Comment: It works for the file you showed in the question, which is space-separated.

Comment: use the `-F` option to `awk` to specify the field separator if it's not whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

Since the file is sorted (grouped by key), you could try this to save some memory and preserve order:

```
awk '
  p!=$1 OFS $2 {
    if(p)print p,v
    p=$1 OFS $2
    v=$3
    next 
  } 
  $3<v {
    v=$3
  } 
  END{
    print p,v
  }
' FS=, OFS=, file
```

or if $1 is a unique key you could also try this:

```
awk '
  p x!=$1 {
    if(p x)print s
    p=$1
    s=$0
    v=$3
    next 
  } 
  $3<v {
    v=$3
  } 
  END{
    print s
  }
' FS=, file
```

Note: if it is csv file with quoted fields then the script would need to become more complex.